# GCP Composer v1.18.6 and 2.0.10 incompatible with CloudSqlProxyRunner

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-composer, cloud-sql-proxy

In my [Composer](https://cloud.google.com/composer) Airflow DAGs, I have been using the [CloudSqlProxyRunner](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/cloud_sql/index.html#airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.cloud_sql.CloudSqlProxyRunner) to connect to my Cloud SQL instance.

However, after updating Google Cloud Composer from v1.18.4 to 1.18.6, my DAG started to encounter a strange error:

```
[2022-04-22, 23:20:18 UTC] {cloud_sql.py:462} INFO - Downloading cloud_sql_proxy from https://dl.google.com/cloudsql/cloud_sql_proxy.linux.x86_64 to /home/airflow/dXhOYoU_cloud_sql_proxy.tmp
[2022-04-22, 23:20:18 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1702} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1330, in _run_raw_task
    self._execute_task_with_callbacks(context)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1457, in _execute_task_with_callbacks
    result = self._execute_task(context, self.task)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1513, in _execute_task
    result = execute_callable(context=context)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/decorators/base.py", line 134, in execute
    return_value = super().execute(context)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 174, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 185, in execute_callable
    return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/gcs/dags/real_time_scoring_pipeline.py", line 99, in get_messages_db
    with SQLConnection() as sql_conn:
  File "/home/airflow/gcs/dags/helpers/helpers.py", line 71, in __enter__
    self.proxy_runner.start_proxy()
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/cloud_sql.py", line 524, in start_proxy
    self._download_sql_proxy_if_needed()
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/cloud_sql.py", line 474, in _download_sql_proxy_if_needed
    raise AirflowException(
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: The cloud-sql-proxy could not be downloaded. Status code = 404. Reason = Not Found
```

Checking manually, https://dl.google.com/cloudsql/cloud_sql_proxy.linux.x86_64 indeed returns a 404.

Looking at the function that raises the exception, [_download_sql_proxy_if_needed](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/22ba59c5f26d1e6fa2ce59e99304628b2f0a0fd9/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/cloud_sql.py#L449), it has this code:

```py
        system = platform.system().lower()
        processor = os.uname().machine
        if not self.sql_proxy_version:
            download_url = CLOUD_SQL_PROXY_DOWNLOAD_URL.format(system, processor)
        else:
            download_url = CLOUD_SQL_PROXY_VERSION_DOWNLOAD_URL.format(
                self.sql_proxy_version, system, processor
            )
```

So, for whatever reason, in both of these latest images of Composer, `processor = os.uname().machine` returns `x86_64`. Previously, it returned `amd64`, and https://dl.google.com/cloudsql/cloud_sql_proxy.linux.amd64 is in fact a valid link to the binary we need.

I replicated this error in Composer 2.0.10 as well.

I am still investigating possible workarounds, but posting this here in case someone else encounters this issue, and has figured out a workaround, and to raise this with Google engineers (who, according to Composer's docs, monitor this tag).

Comment: I've reported this internally and will get the team to take a look as well.

Comment: Looks like this was broken here: https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/22127/files#diff-5992ce7fff93c23c57833df9ef892e11a023494341b80a9fefa8401f91988942L454.

Answer (score 3):

My current workaround is patching the CloudSqlProxyRunner to hardcode the correct URL:

```py
class PatchedCloudSqlProxyRunner(CloudSqlProxyRunner):
    """
    This is a patched version of CloudSqlProxyRunner to provide a workaround for an incorrectly
    generated URL to the Cloud SQL proxy binary.
    """

    def _download_sql_proxy_if_needed(self) -> None:
        download_url = "https://dl.google.com/cloudsql/cloud_sql_proxy.linux.amd64"
        
        # the rest of the code is taken from the original method

        proxy_path_tmp = self.sql_proxy_path + ".tmp"
        self.log.info(
            "Downloading cloud_sql_proxy from %s to %s", download_url, proxy_path_tmp
        )
        # httpx has a breaking API change (follow_redirects vs allow_redirects)
        # and this should work with both versions (cf. issue #20088)
        if "follow_redirects" in signature(httpx.get).parameters.keys():
            response = httpx.get(download_url, follow_redirects=True)
        else:
            response = httpx.get(download_url, allow_redirects=True)  # type: ignore[call-arg]
        # Downloading to .tmp file first to avoid case where partially downloaded
        # binary is used by parallel operator which uses the same fixed binary path
        with open(proxy_path_tmp, "wb") as file:
            file.write(response.content)
        if response.status_code != 200:
            raise AirflowException(
                "The cloud-sql-proxy could not be downloaded. "
                f"Status code = {response.status_code}. Reason = {response.reason_phrase}"
            )

        self.log.info(
            "Moving sql_proxy binary from %s to %s", proxy_path_tmp, self.sql_proxy_path
        )
        shutil.move(proxy_path_tmp, self.sql_proxy_path)
        os.chmod(self.sql_proxy_path, 0o744)  # Set executable bit
        self.sql_proxy_was_downloaded = True
```

And then instantiate it and use it as I would the original CloudSqlProxyRunner:

```py
proxy_runner = PatchedCloudSqlProxyRunner(path_prefix, instance_spec)
proxy_runner.start_proxy()
```

But I am hoping that this is properly fixed by someone at Google soon, by fixing the os.uname().machine value,
or uploading a Cloud SQL proxy binary to the one currently generated in `_download_sql_proxy_if_needed`.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by @enocom this [commit](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/22127/files#diff-5992ce7fff93c23c57833df9ef892e11a023494341b80a9fefa8401f91988942) to support `arm64` download links actually caused a side-effect of generating broken download links. I assume the author of the commit thought that the Cloud SQL Proxy had binaries for each machine type, although in fact there are not Linux `x86_64` links.

I have created an [airflow PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/23299) to hopefully fix the broken links, hopefully it will get merged in soon and resolve this. Will update the thread with any updates.

Update (I've been working with Jack on this): I just merged that PR! When a new version of [the providers](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-providers-google/) is added to PyPI, you'll need to add it to your Composer environment. In the meantime, as a workaround, you could take the fix from Jack's PR and use it as a [local dependency](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/installing-python-dependencies#install-local). (Similar to the other reply here!) If you do this, I highly recommend setting a calendar reminder (maybe a month from now?) to remove the workaround and go back to importing from the provider package, just to make sure you don't miss out on other updates to it! :)

Comment: The fix will be deployed for `apache-airflow-providers-google=7.0.0` the RC should be in beginning of May. In the meantime you can use `apache-airflow-providers-google==6.5.0`